# CSS to only underline text on active and not padding - ajax toolkit tabs

Tags: css, tabs, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to style some ajax toolkit tabs and running into a strange problem.

I want the selected tab to be underlined (bottom border red) but only the text to be underlined within the tab. Currently the selected tab is underlined and includes the padding of the tab. Ive tried lots of variations of using `margin`, `padding` and `box-sizing` but with no luck. Can anyone help ?

This is my CSS

```
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_header
{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_outer
{
    border-left-color:#fff;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    border-top-color:#fff;
}
 
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_inner
{
    border-left-color:#fff;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    border-top-color:#fff;
}
 
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_outer
{
}
 
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_inner
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e3002b; 
}
 
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_outer
{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 1px;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
 
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_inner
{
    border-left-color:#fff;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    border-top-color:#fff;
}
 
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_tab
{
    color: #e3002b;
}
 
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_active
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e3002b;
}
 
 
 
 
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_body
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_inner
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e3002b; 
}
```

to

```
.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_active
{
    text-decoration: underline; 
    text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

Assuming that the text is inside `.ajax__tab_inner`

Comment: that doesn't work. The hover has stopped working and the text and the right padding are underlined ?

Comment: can you post the HTML with it?

Comment: not really - the page is huge - it's really just a standard ajax toolkit tab setup with the css class set to InnerTabStyle - there is 2 rows rows of tabs and I have CSS for the outer set of tabs as well but i've removed that CSS to make sure it's not interfering

Comment: Could you post the section of the HTML that is bothering you?

Comment: i can't - it isn't on this machine - as I mentioned above it's just a standard ajax toolkit tab structure referencing this css file.

Comment: I do see what you mean though - there is another span with the class tab_tab - changing the bottom border of this CSS class gives me exactly what I need

Comment: This is the reason why I was asking you for the HTML

Comment: Sure - I appreciate that - the solution though, that may help other dev with the ajax toolkit tabs, was slightly different. But thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this as Sidsec certainly pointed me in the right direction but the answer is subtly different.

It appears that the HTML rendered from the tabs component gives the following

```
<active tab>
  <outer tab>
    <inner tab>
     <tab tab>
     </>
    </>
  </>
</>
```

Applying the following styles gives exactly what I was looking for:

```
...

.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_tab
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e3002b;
}

.InnerTabStyle .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_tab
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e3002b;
}

...
```